# Arpack and Matlab give different values for eigenvalues

Tags: matlab, finite-element, eigenvalues, complex-arithmetic, arpack

I am solving a generalized eigenvalues problem with inversed complex shift:

$$(M-\sigma J)^{-1}J \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{x} \nu \enspace .$$

My matrices are obtained from a finite element discretization with Getfem++. The jacobian $J$ depends on some parameters. I computed the eigenvalues both with Matlab and directly with Arpack in the same C++ code where I compute the matrices $M$ and $J$. 
When I use Matlab to compute the eigenvalues I load the matrices $M$ and $J$ previously saved in Market Matrix format with Getfem++ and I use the function `eigs`.
Now, in some cases the difference between Arpack eigenvalues and Matlab eigenvalues is really big. In particular, when the values of my parameters are such that I have an eigenvalue with almost zero real part. 
With Arpack the real part is of the order of $10^{-10}$ with Matlab is of the order of $10^{-4}$. In addition, in these cases Matlab gives me some warning about the matrix is ill-conditioned. 
Have you ever experienced such a problem?

P.S. : I also tried to change default options of eigs but I always obtain the same result!

Comment: Are you saving enough digits in your Matrix Market format?

Comment: What value of sigma are you passing to eigs()?

Comment: Yes, there are enough digits. The sigma depends on the parameters. It is near the critical eigenvalue that I am looking for, at least the imaginary part. The real part of the shift is set to 0.001.

Comment: That sigma seems like it is probably OK. Nevertheless, I suggest experimenting with different (larger) values of sigma to try to get rid of that warning message; it seems likely that warning is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yes, maybe. I can try with a bigger real part. But I do not understand why in Arpack I obtain different results. Isn't Matlab calling Arpack functions too?

Comment: How many is enough?

Comment: 0.0004677933806709975,  -3.874105873531737e-05, 4.611944776965112e-20, 4.899144179069118e-20, -3.922450470984894e-05, 1.375629528250193e-19, -0.0001568980188393956, -7.796556344516627e-05... Here's an extract..

Comment: Matlab uses ARPACK but it will sometimes change your calls around in an advantageous way, for example, it'll find the largest eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ rather than the smallest eigenvalues of $A$. In addition to Bill Greene's suggestion to try different values of $\sigma$, you could also try using the eigensolver [SLEPc](http://slepc.upv.es/). I've had good luck with it where ARPACK fails.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I changed the shift but it's the same.